# How to add shadow around round button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-background, android-shape

I want to use round `Button` in my app and add shadow behind it/around the corner. You can create that shadow if your `Button` is circular by adding `gradient` and setting it to radial will create round shadow around the button (because solid color is covered by real `Button` background). But if you want to use round button, but with rectangular shape, gradient is still circular and I cannot use it.
Is there any way how to create rectangular gradient with same effect?

Another hack how to create shadow is by using `9patch` shadow generator, but it is working only with certain dpi. (If you generate .png shadow for `200x100dp` `Button`, it will cover corners exactly only for `200x100dp` `Button` and its not generic solution)

```
<gradient
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:centerColor="@color/grey"
    android:startColor="@color/grey"
    android:gradientRadius="200dp"
    android:type="radial" />
```

Comment: [Create Shadows and Clip Views](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping)

Comment: you can also add elevation property to your button.

Comment: Use the [MaterialButton](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md)